# JQuery Number of children

Tags: jquery, count, loops

I have a moderately simple problem, and I am trying to figure out the best approach to implement it.

For those wondering, this is used to scrape data from a non-editable page (can add css,js, but the rest of the content is closed source and not available for editing)

I am iterating through an element (`tr` for example), and I only want to look at the cases where a certain number of `td` elements are present.

Eg, For every `tr`, I only want to consider the case where it has 3 `td` children

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = $('tr').filter( function(){
  return $(this).children('td').length === 3;
});
```

You can then do any kind of scraping you like. A simple example:

```
result.each( function(i,e){ // for each row
  // e = one of the selected rows
  $(e).children('td').each( function(i,e){ // for each td in the row
    your_scraping_function( e.text() ); // etc.
  });
});
```

As @patrick points out below, you can of course chain the scraping process directly to the output of the `filter()` if it makes sense for your code.

Edit: Added `'td'` selector in `children()`. Belt and suspenders.

Edit: Added example of how to walk through results, as per OP comment.

Comment: beat me to it. actually, I would put a 'tr' selector inside children() just to be specific, since it can also take th tags, technically.

Comment: How could I iterate from these results?

Comment: @Tesserex, I assume you mean `td`. Can't hurt. Added.

Comment: @Steven, one way is to just assign the result of that selector to a variable (as updated above).

Comment: +1 Or you could just chain the `.each()` after the `.filter()` (or do the work *in* the filter for that matter).